# How To Read Etherscan Token Transfers

Tags: transactions, erc-20, etherscan, ico

I'm noticing a lot of ether transfers into ERC20 token contracts months after the token's ICO finished.  I am wondering how is this possible, and where these tokens are coming from, since tokens are only distributed by a company during and ICO?

An example:https://etherscan.io/address/0xa74476443119A942dE498590Fe1f2454d7D4aC0d
Here we see addresses sending 0 ether to 'GolemToken' contract in exchange for tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

0 value calls ( no eth ), are calls to contract code.

In the case of this contract, they're token "transfer" calls.

If you look at the transaction details you will see an "input data" field that shows this quite clearly.

example: https://etherscan.io/tx/0x51592291e8640fb908dcc534215497184ef39f1eb5ba517bde8d9fe929bfca6b